# Install Flash Player plugin on xulrunner 22.0

Tags: flash, xulrunner, geckofx

I am using GeckoFX running on xulrunner 22.0, and it works fine. But when it comes to load a website with Flash, then it does not load the Flash content.

I have been trying to install the Flash Player plugin to the xulrunner but I've failed miserably.

The installation I followed was to copy the **NPSWF32_11_7_700_224.dll** file to the **/plugins/** directory in the xulrunner directory. and the **FlashPlayerApp.exe** to the xulrunner directory itself. And still nothing.

Anybody knows how to get this thing working?

Comment: In my case the problem was in that I used <iframe> instead of <browser> to show web content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to disable blocklisting

```
GeckoPreferences.Default["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;
```

Comment: You're a genius @vmas!!!, where did you get that super secret line of code?? I just added the line after the initialization of the Xpcom and it works. Thanks. Anyways, to anybody else dealing with this, there's **no** need to copy any file anywhere, just install the Flash Player (Shockwave) and xulrunner will load it using the HKLM/Software/MozillaPlugins/. [Gecko Basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Basics)

Comment: This is an old problem. I tested the Geckofx 18 with files from Firefox 18. In this case, you can see the placeholder that says: "This plugin is disabled". In Geckofx/Firefox-22 there is no placeholder, but works  in a similar way.