# geckofx webbrowser doesnt play audio in windows forms c#

Tags: c#, audio, geckofx

i am doing a desktop application where a local html file is opened and displayed..
i am using this for a kiosk.
i have tried using webbrowser control for opening the website in c#
i have used www.kids.sandiegozoo.org as sample website to test audio
when i open a website .everything works fine but the audio doesnt play.
when the website is opened the audio symbol which is present on topright corner is also not visible.

for the audio to be played do i need to add any other plugin???

i have also used geckofx browser control and this also does the same.there is no difference

i am confused what is the problem.
please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web site uses flash. The flash player plugging need to be enabled in geckofx for this to work.

See this SO answer: [flash:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421532/install-flash-player-plugin-on-xulrunner-22-0)
[Install Flash Player plugin on xulrunner 22.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421532/install-flash-player-plugin-on-xulrunner-22-0)